# DENSE_RANK treat NULL distinctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, dense-rank

Given the following

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        A INT,
        B INT,
        C INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 1, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 1, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 1, 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 1, 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 1, 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 1, 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 2, 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 2, 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 1, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 1, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 1, 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 2, 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 2, 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 2, NULL

SELECT A, B, C, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A,B,C DESC) AS rank
FROM @Table
```

The result is:

```
A   B   C   rank
1   1   2   1
1   1   2   1
1   1   2   1
1   1   1   2
1   1   NULL    3
1   1   NULL    3
1   2   2   4
1   2   1   5
2   1   1   6
2   1   NULL    7
2   1   NULL    7
2   2   1   8
2   2   1   8
2   2   NULL    9
```

I want the instances of `1 1 NULL` and `2 1 NULL` to be distinct ranks. I want NULLs to be treated like they are an unknown value and not to group nulls together.

An acceptable answer could be

```
A   B   C   rank
1   1   2   1
1   1   2   1
1   1   2   1
1   1   1   2
1   1   NULL    3
1   1   NULL    4
1   2   2   5
1   2   1   6
2   1   1   7
2   1   NULL    8
2   1   NULL    9
2   2   1   10
2   2   1   10
2   2   NULL    11
```

I don't care if the null values are at the beginning or the end, that is. I am not actually ranking things. I am using `DENSE_RANK` as a means to give each group a unique number.

I am using SQL server 2014

Comment: I'm seeing 1 1 NULL = Rank 3; whereas 2 1 NULL = Rank 7.  Aren't those distinct?

Comment: No, DENSE_RANK treats NULLs as the same -- hence the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least you can do it this way by adding a dummy column that gets a unique value when C is null:

```
SELECT A, B, C, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A,B,C DESC, dummy) AS rank
FROM (
    select *, case when C is null then row_number() over (order by (select null)) end as dummy
    from @Table
) X
```

Comment: But, what will happen if we have new row_number value same to existing column, here it is the column c